# Google script indexOf not working for custom element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

this is a sample of my script in google sheet. How can I set the indexOf method to work in all cases?

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MySheet");
var myArray = sheet.getRange("A7:A10").getValues();

//this works (of course) -> returns 2
sheet.getRange('L1').setValue(myArray.indexOf(myArray[2]));

//this don't work (but it can be my fault in typing..) -> returns -1
sheet.getRange('L2').setValue(myArray.indexOf("Thing"));

//this don't work (why?) -> returns -1
sheet.getRange('L3').setValue(myArray.indexOf(sheet.getRange("A9").getValues()));

//to check my value, this works
Browser.msgBox(myArray[2]);
```

Where am I wrong? All contents in cells are string.

Comment: @Cooper thank you, but it still returns -1.

Comment: @TheMaster have you any idea how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this and I finally realized that I needed to convert the data back to a one dimensional array.  This was the code I was playing with.  It's not exactly like yours but it does a similar sort of thing.

```
function test() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh.getRange('A1:D5').clear();
  sh.getRange('A1:A5').setValues([["One"],["Twp"],["Three"],["Four"],["Five"]]);//just intializing my data
  var mA = sh.getRange("A1:A5").getValues();
  var dA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<mA.length;i++){
    sh.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(mA[i][0]);
    dA.push(mA[i][0]);
    sh.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(dA.indexOf(mA[i][0]));
    sh.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(dA.indexOf(sh.getRange(i+1,2).getValue()));
  }
}
```

So you could add this to your code to get it to work.

```
var myArray = sheet.getRange("A7:A10").getValues();
  var mA=[];
  for(var i=0;myArray.length;i++){
    mA.push(myArray[i][0]);
  }
```

And then use `mA.indexOf()` instead of `myArray.indexOf();`

Answer (score 2):

`getValues()` returns an array of arrays (also known as a two-dimensional array).

So basically if you had a sheet populated with data as follows:

```
+---+------+----+--------+
|   |  A   | B  |   C    |
+---+------+----+--------+
| 1 | John |    | Doe    |
| 2 | Jane |    | Doe    |
| 3 | John | Q. | Public |
+---+------+----+--------+
```

Calling `getValues()` would give you an 2D array like this:

```
var myArray = sheet.getRange('A1:C3').getValues();

Logger.log(myArray);

/* Logger output will look something like this:
[
    ["John", null, "Doe"],
    ["Jane", null, "Doe"],
    ["John", "Q.", "Public"]
]
*/
```

So going back to your sheet, `myArray.indexOf("Thing")`is trying to match the string object "Thing" against an array object; that will always result in -1. You need to refactor your code to take two dimensional arrays into account.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but in my case the range is one column only, so I would expect to confront the string with mono-dimensional object (and this condition will never change in my code): so how can I solve my situation and use indexOf (or can have a suggestion for another method)?

Comment: @marcoresk Even with a single column you're going to get an array of arrays. Use `Logger.log()` to log your`myArray` variable and you'll see that its a 2D array. Once you adjust your code to account for that you'll be good to go.

Comment: @marcoresk Another thing, `getValues()` **always** returns a 2D Array. You can verify this by [checking the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).